# Random Riley Riddle Number 2

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, knowledge

My Prefix is a place to stay,
but famously said to go away.

My Infix happens where you might find a trooper.
When two become one, it really is super.

My Suffix means to ignore,
but spell it differently, and you'll be sure.

My Whole is what the original Riley,
created that makes us so smiley.

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are an

> INNOVATION.

My Prefix is a place to stay, 
but famously said to go away.

> There was no room at the INN in Bethlehem.

My Infix happens where you might find a trooper. 
When two become one, it really is super.

> This is referring to NOVA troopers from Star Wars; and also superNOVAs.

My Suffix means to ignore,

> To SHUN something or someone.

but spell it differently, and you'll be sure.

> SHUN spelled differently is TION.

My Whole is what the original Riley, 
created that makes us so smiley.

> Riley created a "new" riddle format for Puzzling.SE, this is an INNOVATION to be sure.

Comment: Damn that was quick, well done!